# Prove $a^m\equiv a^{m-\phi(m)}\pmod m$ for all positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $a,m$ are positive integers, then $$a^m\equiv a^{m-\phi(m)}\pmod m.\tag 1$$

If gcd$(a,m)=1$ then this is [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Denote gcd$(a,m)=k$ and $a=xk,m=yk$ then we need to prove
$$a^{m-\phi(m)}(a^{\phi(m)}-1)\equiv 0\pmod m\tag2$$

If gcd$(k,y)=1$ then $k\mid a^{m-\phi(m)}$ and $y\mid a^{\phi(y)}-1\mid a^{\phi(m)}-1$, hence $(2)$ holds.

However, how to prove it if gcd$(y,k)\gt1$?

Comment: You mean $m=yk$ in the definition of $y$, right?  This probably boils down to proving that $m-\phi(m)$ is large enough compared to the highest exponent of any prime power dividing $m$ (which is bounded by $\log_2(m)$, for starters).